# Advanced sorting in Excel partially alphabetical (grouped)

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

I need to sort some text cells, but it's not (entirely) alphabetical.

[image]

It should be alphabetical, but grouped. So first all the non 45 or 90 degrees then the 45 and then the 90.

Some background info:
The 45 en 90 are degrees. These are article numbers for hydraulic couplings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You need a helper column to solve the issue:*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Enter this formula in cell P3 and fill down.

  ```
  =IF(COUNT(SEARCH({45},O3)),2,IF(COUNT(SEARCH({90},O3)),3,1))
  ```

**N.B.**

- This formula finds position of 45 & 90 in every cell and the IF logic assigns numbers to make group.
- For 45 is 2, for 90 is 3 and for rest is 1

*This may vary if & when the data combination changes.*

- Now select O2:P8.
- Reach to Custom Sort, and set **Sort by Column** *Helper*, for **Sort on** *Values* and **Order** *Smallest to Largest*.

[image]

- Finish with Ok.

*You get records in desire order.*

[image]

- For neatness later on you may hide Helper column.
- Adjust cell references & others, in the formula as needed.

Comment: Glad to help you @vdclouis ,, keep asking ☺